# How do I create a Friend model with accept field?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I want to create a social networking app, where we can add friends and see their posts.
In this I want to create a friend model like this:

```
class Friend(models.Model):
    from = models.ForeignKey(User)
    to = models.ForeignKey(User)
    accepted = models.NullBooleanField(null=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('from', 'to')
```

I am just confused about reverse relation between *from* and *to*. For example, if *A* is friend of *B*, then *B* is also friend of *A*. I am having problem in getting all friends of a user, because the user can exist in *from* as well as in *to*.

Answer (score 0):

i think your model should look like this

```
class Friend(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    friend = models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name='friend',blank=True)
    accepted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make two `related_name`s for the relations, since now you refer twice to the same model:

```
class Friend(models.Model):
    from = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='friend_from', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    to = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='friend_to', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    accepted = models.BooleanField(default=False, editable=False)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('from', 'to')
```

You can obtain the *accepted* friends of a *`my_user`* with:

```
from django.db.models import Q

User.objects.filter(
    Q(friend_from__to=my_user, friend_from__accepted=True) |
    Q(friend_to__from=my_user, friend_to__accepted=True)
)
```